# Multiple problems trying to run a Chai OpenCL benchmark on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, opencl, benchmarking

I am totally new in this area related to OpenCL and Ubuntu, but I am learning and trying to run some benchmarks but I have the following errors shown below. I believe that I did everything correctly related to installing CUDA (I have NVIDIA graphics card) and linking with the benchmark, but the errors below still appear. Could someone help me, please?

Also, to link correctly, the first thing that I did was to locate the include and lib directories were and then used the command that they used, like this:

```
export CHAI_OCL_LIB=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/
export CHAI_OCL_INC=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/include/
```

To do this I located where OpenCL was, as shown on the image below, to get the adress.

[Locate OpenCL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNmf1.png)

**Errors**:

```
support/ocl.h:106:9: note: suggested alternative: ‘cl_context_properties’
     cl_queue_properties prop[] = {0};
main.cpp:180:38: error: ‘clSVMAlloc’ was not declared in this scope
 Node *           nodes = (Node *)clSVMAlloc(ocl.clContext, CL_MEM_SVM_FINE_GRAIN_BUFFER, sizeof(Node) * n_nodes, 0);
main.cpp:316:5: error: ‘clSVMFree’ was not declared in this scope
 clSVMFree(ocl.clContext, nodes);
 ^~~~~~~~~
```

[Bash errors related to trying to run the Chai Benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhQDV.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the errors it looks that the benchmark requires `OpenCL 2.x` to be built and `Nvidia` support is up to `OpenCL 1.2`.

So to build the benchmark install `OpenCL 2.x`. Depending on the Ubuntu version it can be available to install straight away via: `apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev`.

Comment: It says "ocl-icd-opencl-dev is already the newest version (2.2.11-1ubuntu1)." and I run this command.

Comment: And have you pointed CHAI env variables to that different OpenCL location?

Comment: What different OpenCL location?

Comment: You previously pointed `CHAI_OCL_LIB/INC` to cuda location. Now try ocl-icd-opencl-dev location.

Comment: Yep, it worked. I can now compile, but when I try to execute, it shows the message "GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER Allocation error at main.cpp, 201"

Comment: Show how you execute the benchmark and the whole error message. Also the code around main.cpp:201

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late answer, I was very busy. So, I'm executing it as they show on their github page, (https://github.com/chai-benchmarks/chai), I'm just doing 'make' and then './bfs' and this messsage appears  "GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER Allocation error at main.cpp, 201", nothing more. When I try different benchmarks, but from Chai, the same message appears, but with a different number in the end.